# sql data type bit

Tags: c#

I have  sql data type bit and i want to ask

```
if(dr[2] != null)
```

What changes should make it?
Sorry for the mistakes I'm not local.

Comment: How are you getting the data into C#? Are you using a DataSet, DataReader or LINQ to SQL (or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

To check if the column value is NULL, use DBNull.Value:

```
if (dr[2] != DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **dr** is a DataReader, calling dr.IsDBNull(2) will tell you whether it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote like this and the value is NULL dr[2] != System.DBNull.Value 
and this answer 
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: You should edit your original question with that information. Welcome to the Stack :)